# Simple RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test/index.php?topic=rules
```

I want to rewrite it to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test/topic/rules
```

I tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?topic=$1
```

Didn't do anything. I used a 3rd party website to generate this rewrite code so maybe it's incorrect, I dunno. Is there anything in Apache that could be causing this to not work?

Comment: Where's that rule configured?

Comment: Where's that final slash in the URL?

Comment: It's in `.htaccess` in the `test` directory along with the `index.php`. I don't know anything about missing a slash. That's why I'm asking the question in case something is wrong with the rule...

Comment: @Jakobud Your rule specifies a trailing slash.  So, `http://www.mysite.com/test/topic/rules` will never be rewritten, only `http://www.mysite.com/test/topic/rules/` will.  Which behavior is needed?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `/test/` in the URL.  The leading ^ your rule means "start of path".  You probably want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test/topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /test/index.php?topic=$1
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Oh, I suppose it matters where the rule lives.  Possibly nevermind...

Comment: What if I wanted this to be path independent? What if I wanted it to work in `/test/` or `/test/whatever/` or `/123/345/testing123/`?

Comment: You could try something like `^/(.*)/topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /$1/index.php?topic=$2` (totally untested, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match the query string in RewriteRule, so you need to use RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} topic=(.*)
RewriteRule test/index.php test/topic/%1? [L]
```